# Lemmatize df column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk, stemming, lemmatization

I am trying to lemmatize content in a df but the function I wrote isn't working. Prior to trying to lemmatize the data in the column looked like this.

[image]

Then I ran the following code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 

# Init the Wordnet Lemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize_text(text):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in text]  

df['content'] = df["content"].apply(lemmatize_text)
print(df.content)
```

Now the content column looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure what i did wrong, but I am just trying to lemmatize the data in the content column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lemmatizing each char instead of word. Your function should look like this instead:

```
def lemmatize_text(text):
    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    return ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in text.split(' ')])
```